# What is the proper way in Python to define a dataclass that has both an auto generated __init__ and an additional init2 from a dict of values

Tags: python, data-class, python-dataclasses

In Python, I have a dataclass that holds over a dozen members. I use it to create a dict that I post **into ElasticSearch**.

Now I want to get a dict **from ElasticSearch** and use it to initialize the dataclass.

Since:

1. Python doesn't allow to create a second __ init __ with a different signature.
2. I don't want to manually write the __ init __ which is auto-generated just to add an optional parameter
3. I don't want to add an optional parameter to accept the dict, just so that the __ init __ remains auto-generated.

I thought of adding a 2nd method **init2**, which will return an instance of the dataclass and parse the passed dict parameter into the auto-generated __ init __ method.

---

I would appriciate your input to decide if my suggested solution below is the correct implementation.

Also, Can this implementation be considered as a type of factory?

Thanks.

---

> Follow up: Since the JSON\dictionary I get from the ES request is:
>
> 1. Has exactly the same keywords as the dataclass
> 2. Is flat, i.d., there are no nested objects.
>
> I could simply pass the values as a **dict into the the auto-generated __ init __ method.
>
> See my answer below for this specific case:

---

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyData:
    name: str
    age: int = 17

    @classmethod
    def init_from_dict(cls, values_in_dict: dict):
        # Original line using MyData was fixed to use cls, following @ForceBru 's comment
        # return MyData(values_in_dict['name'], age=values_in_dict['age'])
        return cls(values_in_dict['name'], age=values_in_dict['age'])

my_data_1: MyData = MyData('Alice')
print(my_data_1)

my_data_2: MyData = MyData('Bob', 15)
print(my_data_2)

values_in_dict_3: dict = {
    'name': 'Carol',
    'age': 20
}

my_data_3: MyData = MyData.init_from_dict(values_in_dict_3)
print(my_data_3)

# Another init which uses the auto-generated __init__ works in this specific
# case because the values' dict is flat and the keywords are the same as the
# parameter names in the dataclass.
# This allows me to do this
my_data_4: MyData = MyData(**values_in_dict_3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a potential bug in your code. Consider this:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, value):
        return Thing(value, value + 1)

class AnotherOne(Thing):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a + 1, b + 2
```

Now, if you run `AnotherOne.from_int(6)` you'd get a `Thing` object:

```
>>> AnotherOne.from_int(6)
<__main__.Thing object at 0x8f4a04c>
```

...while you probably wanted to create a `AnotherOne` object!

To fix this, create the object like this:

```
class Thing:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, value):
        return cls(value, value + 1)  # Use `cls` instead of `Thing`
```

I think your code is otherwise fine: indeed, one of the usages of `classmethod` is providing other ways to initialize an instance of a class than using `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, Can this implementation be considered as a type of factory?

Yes, it is a common pattern to add `from_<type>` `classmethod`s as python does not support method overloading.

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the follow up section of the question, the _source section of the ElasticSearch response has the same keywords as the dataclass' parameters and is flat, meaning there is no nested dictionaries in the JSON\dict.

This allows me to implement the following.

My response's "_source" in the elastic search looks like this

```
response = {
  "_index": "env1",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "e3c85",
  "_score": 0.105360515,
  "_source": {
    "name": "RaamEEIL",
    "age": "19"
  }
}
```

So I could simply do:

```
my_data = MyData(**response['_source'])
```

This passes the values as key:value pairs into the __ init __ method and since the names match, it works smoothly.