# Call the generated __init__ from custom constructor in dataclass for defaults

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Is it possible to benefit from `dataclasses.field`, especially for default values, but using a custom constuctor? I know the `@dataclass` annotation sets default values in the generated `__init__`, and won't do it anymore if I replace it. So, is it possible to replace the generated `__init__`, and to still call it inside?

```py
@dataclass
class A:
    l: list[int] = field(default_factory=list)
    i: int = field(default=0)
        
    def __init__(self, a: Optional[int]): # completely different args than instance attributes
        self.call_dataclass_generated_init() # call generated init to set defaults
        if a is not None: # custom settings of attributes
            self.i = 2*a
```

A workaround would be to define `__new__` instead of overriding `__init__`, but I prefer to avoid that.

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775717/calling-generated-init-in-custom-init-override-on-dataclass) is quite close, but the answers only address the specific use-case that is given as a code example. Also, I don't want to use `__post_init__` because I need to use `__setattr__` which is an issue for static type checking, and it doesn't help tuning the arguments that `__init__` will take anyway.
- I don't want to [use a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849331/what-is-the-proper-way-in-python-to-define-a-dataclass-that-has-both-an-auto-gen) either, I really want callers to use the custom constructor.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986725/dataclass-attribute-missing-when-using-explicit-init-constructor-and-default) is also close, but it's only about explaining *why* the new constructor replaces the generated one, not about *how* to still call the latter (there's also a reply suggesting to use Pydantic, but I don't want to have to subclass `BaseModel`, because it will mess my inheritance).

So, in short, I want to benefit from `dataclass`'s feature to have default values for attributes, without cumbersome workarounds. Note that raw default values is not an option for me because it sets class attributes:

```py
class B:
    a: int = 0 # this will create B.a class attribute, and vars(B()) will be empty
    l: list[int] = [] # worse, a mutable object will be shared between instances
```

Comment: so, you know about [`InitVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) too? `__post_init__` will get them, and they will not be dataclass fields.

Comment: The class method *is* the custom constructor. I don't see the benefit in forcing the name of the class to do something other than what it usually does.

Comment: `__post_init__` doesn't allow the arguments to be different from the instance attributes as required. As for class methods, I required not to use them because they change the behavior of the class (making it impossible to naturally include it in inheritance for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I perceive it, the cleaner approach there is to have an alternative classmethod to use as your constructor: this way, the dataclass would work exactly as intended and you could just do:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class A:
    l: list[int] = field(default_factory=list)
    i: int = field(default=0)
     
    @classmethod
    def new(cls, a: Optional[int]=0): # completely different args than instance attributes
        # creates a new instance with default values:
        instance = cls()
        # if one wants to have more control over the instance creation, it is possible to call __new__ and __init__ manually:
        # instance = cls.__new__(cls)
        # instance.__init__()
        if a is not None: # custom settings of attributes
            i = 2*a
            
        return instance
```

But if you don't want an explicit constructor method, and really need to call just `A()`, it can be done by creating a decorator, that will be applied after `@dataclass` - it can then move `__init__` to another name. The only thng being that your custom `__init__` has to be called another name, otherwise `@dataclass`  won't create the method.

```
def custom_init(cls):
    cls._dataclass_generated_init = cls.__init__
    cls.__init__ = cls.__custom_init__
    return cls

@custom_init    
@dataclass
class A:
    l: list[int] = field(default_factory=list)
    i: int = field(default=0)
        
    def __custom_init__(self, a: Optional[int]): # completely different args than instance attributes
        self._dataclass_generated_init() # call generated init to set defaults
        if a is not None: # custom settings of attributes
            i = 2*a
            ...
        print("custom init called")
```

Comment: The class method doesn't need to invoke `__new__` and `__init__` expclitly; it just needs to call `cls` like you normally would: `instance = cls()`.

Comment: As stated in my question, the class method is not an option for me (because it changes the class' behavior, for example preventing natural inheritance). The decorator technique is a nice workaround, and works with inheritance as well. It sill has the downside that IDEs and type checkers won't understand its magic. But I'm accepting the answer, until a new one eventually finds a solution to this point.